# Take unique values of a column and add each in unique column in same row as `by` in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Apologies in advance...I couldn't articulate a better title.

Here is the problem:

I am working with a data.table and have grouped rows using 'by'. This results in the same number of rows as the unique values of the column of interest. For each unique 'by' value (in this example, 'lat_lon'), I want to take the unique values in another column (ID) and add them to the same row as the unique by column.

```
Here is an example:    
    lat_lon              ID
 1: 42.04166667_-80.4375 26D25
 2: 42.04166667_-80.4375 26D26
 3: 42.04166667_-80.3125 26D34
 4: 42.04166667_-80.3125 26D35
 5: 42.04166667_-80.3125 26D36
 6:      42.125_-80.1875 26D41
 7:      42.125_-80.1875 27C46
 8:      42.125_-80.1875 27D42
 9: 42.04166667_-80.1875 26D43
10: 42.04166667_-80.1875 26D45
11: 42.04166667_-80.1875 27D44
12: 42.04166667_-80.1875 27D46
13: 42.29166667_-79.8125 27B76
14: 42.20833333_-80.0625 27C53
15: 42.20833333_-80.0625 27C54
16:      42.125_-80.0625 27C55
17:      42.125_-80.0625 27C56
18:      42.125_-80.0625 27D51
19:      42.125_-80.0625 27D52
```

What I really want is this:

```
lat_lon              ID.1  ID.2    ID.3 ID.4 ID.5 ID.6 ID.7 ID.8 ID.9 ID.10
42.04166667_-80.4375 26D25 26D26   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
42.04166667_-80.3125 26D34 26D35 26D36  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
...   
42.125_-80.0625      27C55 27C56 27D51 27D52 NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Thank you for your patience and helpful comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a `data.table` solution, adding a idx column (`rn`) first then pivot using `dcast.data.table` would help:

```
dcast.data.table(dat[, rn := paste0("ID.", seq_len(.N)), by=.(lat_lon)], 
    lat_lon ~ rn, value.var="ID")

#                 lat_lon  ID.1  ID.2  ID.3  ID.4
# 1: 42.04166667_-80.1875 26D43 26D45 27D44 27D46
# 2: 42.04166667_-80.3125 26D34 26D35 26D36    NA
# 3: 42.04166667_-80.4375 26D25 26D26    NA    NA
# 4:      42.125_-80.0625 27C55 27C56 27D51 27D52
# 5:      42.125_-80.1875 26D41 27C46 27D42    NA
# 6: 42.20833333_-80.0625 27C53 27C54    NA    NA
# 7: 42.29166667_-79.8125 27B76    NA    NA    NA
```

data:

```
dat <- fread("lat_lon              ID
42.04166667_-80.4375 26D25
42.04166667_-80.4375 26D26
42.04166667_-80.3125 26D34
42.04166667_-80.3125 26D35
42.04166667_-80.3125 26D36
42.125_-80.1875 26D41
42.125_-80.1875 27C46
42.125_-80.1875 27D42
42.04166667_-80.1875 26D43
42.04166667_-80.1875 26D45
42.04166667_-80.1875 27D44
42.04166667_-80.1875 27D46
42.29166667_-79.8125 27B76
42.20833333_-80.0625 27C53
42.20833333_-80.0625 27C54
42.125_-80.0625 27C55
42.125_-80.0625 27C56
42.125_-80.0625 27D51
42.125_-80.0625 27D52")
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you very much. BTW, for future reference, what title would have been a better articulation of my problem?

Comment: I don’t know. Maybe spread column with duplicate ids by group?

Answer (score 0):

This is a departure from data.table (not that it can't be done there I'm sure but I'm less familiar) into the tidyverse

```
require(tidyr)
require(dplyr)
wide_data <- dat %>% group_by(lat_lon) %>% mutate(IDno = paste0("ID.",row_number())) %>% spread(IDno, ID)
```

This assumes that there are no duplicated lines with an ID repeated for a lat_lon. You could add `distinct()` to the chain before the grouping if this isn't the case